# Using Symfony NamespacedAttributeBags in a Controller

Tags: php, symfony, session, symfony-3.4

It's my first time using `NamespacedAttributeBag` so I try the following code but it gives me an exception "**The SessionBagInterface TestData is not registered.**" when I call it from another location, also inside the same controller.

Controller:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request, SessionInterface $session)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();

    $bag = new NamespacedAttributeBag();
    $bag->setName('TestData');
    $bag->set("Type", "Dummy");

    $session->registerBag($bag);
}

public function getDataAction(Request $request, SessionInterface $session)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $bag = $session->getBag('TestData');
}
```

What I want to archive is to define a bag with a couple of attributes (arrays) and use this bag on another function or controller.

The expeption says that the bag is not defined and I can see it is true when I dump the session (`dump($session)`) inside getDataAction. I can see only two default bags `attributes` and `flashes` but is missing `TestData`.

I searched for a more complete example of this but I did not find anything very useful. I don't have it very clear if this can't be used as I want or I'm missing something important.

Comment: Cannot register a bag when the session is already started

Comment: I get that error when I do `$session->start()` before registering a bag, but when I remove it or put it just after registering the bag it works fine. Also, I have access to the bag and to the data from the actual function. But when I try to get that bag from another function on the same controller I get the "is not registered" error.

Answer (score 2):

On Symfony 4.2,

In order to use the NamespacedAttributeBag project-wise, you can override the "**session.attribute_bag**" service in the **config/services.yaml** :

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      
        autoconfigure: true  
 ...
    'session.attribute_bag':
         class: 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\NamespacedAttributeBag'
```

and now use your namespacing for the user's session data from the controller without any other configuration :

```
class DossierController extends AbstractController {
    public function index(Request $request) {
       $request->getSession()->set('namespace1/categoryA/value1', $value);
    }
}
```